# UIImage not being allocated any memory using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, graphic

I have made a program for image effects but when I try to add the effects like photoshop using the code below the image is not allocated any memory and therefore the resulting image is not shown.

```
UIImage *bottomImage = originalImage;
UIImage *upperImage = originalImage;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sizeR, YES, imageBeforeEffect.scale);
[bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, sizeR.width, sizeR.height)];
 [upperImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, sizeR.width, sizeR.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeDarken alpha:1.0];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Did you add `UIGraphicsEndImageContext();` after your code?

Comment: Yes I did add it before just edited the code ... :)

Comment: How exactly do you know that no memory is allocated? What are you doing to show the image?

Comment: To show the image im putting it into a document directory to see if any data is allocated to the memory but the data has 0 bytes ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your sizeR has got any frame... put a break - point and check it. If there is no frame then the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` will not work.

Comment: Thnx.... I did not knw this .... It was an amazing solution .... The best so far .... fantastic !!!!!